# Maximize the sum between two lists of integers? (with restrictions)

Tags: python, algorithm

Recently this was given to me as an interview question which I couldn't solve fast enough.

If you have two lists, and you want to maximize the sum between them, but you can only take one entry at a time and if want to jump to the other list, you have to skip an entry, how would you do it?

For example, you have two cities, LA and New York, and you can collect money in both cities. You can travel to the other city but to do so you have to skip one entry, how would you maximize your money? Assuming that the number of days you have to collect the money is <= to the number of days in NY and LA (the two lists).

Here are two example lists:

LA:  [300, 400, 800, 900]

NY:  [829, 450, 950, 300, 500, 300]

You can take the 300 and then the 400. OR, you can take the 300, travel the next day (skipping the 400 and 450) and take the 950 in NY.

What path could you take that would give you the greatest sum? This is what I have so far:

```
def maximize(n, la_income, ny_income):
 "Assume n <= len(sf_income), n <= len(ny_income)"
    ny_optimals=defaultdict()
    la_optimals=defaultdict()
    for e in range(0,len(sf_income),-1):
        if la_optimal[e+1]>ny_optimal[e+2]:
            la_optimal[e]=la_income[e]+la_optimal[e+1]
        else:
            la_optimal[e]=la_income[e]+ny_optimal[e+2]
```

I'm trying to create two lists of optimal incomes but this way seems very unpythonic. What is a quick and pythonic way to solve this problem?

Comment: are you asking about the algorithm or the most pythonic way of implementing the idea from your code?

Comment: Pretty straightforward dynamic programming problem.  Choose the max of (staying put and taking the next entry), or (switching and skipping an entry), recursively.  Add memoization and ta-dah.

Comment: I guess both the algorithm and the best way to implement it in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a spot of recursive searching?

```
LA = [300, 400, 800, 900]

NY = [829, 450, 950, 300, 500, 300]

def search(now, nxt):
    if len(nxt) < 2:
        return now
    elif not now:
        return nxt[1:]
    stick = [now[0]] + search(now[1:], nxt[1:])
    switch = search(nxt[1:], now[1:])
    return max((stick, switch), key=sum)

print(search(LA, NY))
```

As roippi points out in the comments, memoization will improve performance.

Comment: Yup.  (you should rename `next` :-))

Comment: I don't think this gets the correct answer. It returns 2500, but I think the max is 2700 (stay with LA till it's exhausted, switch to NY to pick up 300: 300+400+800+900+300=2700). Maybe I'm misunderstanding the requirements?

Comment: @dano ah, true. The approach is sound, implementation obviously not so!

Comment: Two minor changes to fix it, it seems: change `if len(now) < 2:` to `if len(now) < 1:` And on the line you calculate `stick`, change `search(now[1:], nxt[:1])` to `search(now[1:], nxt[1:])`

Comment: One question, if you don't know the starting city, how would this be modified? You can't simply calculate max(nxt[0],now[0]) since that messes up the recursion...

Comment: @jon234 just call the function twice: `max((search(NY, LA), search(LA, NY)), key=sum)` (spoiler alert: just stick to NY)